# Errors in Android Studio - some strange error

Tags: java, android

Interesting thing happened. I'm just learning to use android studio and xml in general. And I have a big problem. The whole project worked without any problems, after running the reboot program, the android studio jumped out of the errors that prevented the creation of the preview. Can anyone write me what is wrong? I paste the code below with errors.

> Errors: Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details
>
> Error:(64) error: mismatched tag.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/zdjecie"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/swieta"
        android:text="and all Udacity Students"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/swieta"
        android:text="Best wishes for Google"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/swieta"
        android:text="Happy New Year"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/swieta"
        android:text="from Kamila"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to **clean** and **rebuild** project.

Comment: I did it, unfortunately the problem is exactly the same

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is not well-formed because of your root element.  The `/>` prematurely closes that element.  So change

```
<RelativeLayout
...
android:padding="16dp"/>
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout
...
android:padding="16dp">
```

and you should be all set.

(Note that `<Foo />` is shorthand for `<Foo></Foo>`)